# Change Default Try-Catch Variable Name VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, variables, try-catch

I was wondering if it was possible to change the default variable name that shows up in the auto-complete for a Try-Catch block. It populates as:

```
Try

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I want it so it populates as:

```
Try

Catch excError As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using Code Snippets... http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/code-snippets-visual-studio